# ProgressDialog not executing the first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I've got an Activity that implements a retained fragment to perform a time consuming task. This allows me to rotate the screen without loosing a reference to my async task and without stopping it from being executed. I have a button on the activity to launch the Async task. Everytime the activity is created, for example due to a rotated screen, the activity checks if its retained fragment has an async task running. If so, it shows the progressDialog to let the user know there are still some tasks running on the background. I attach the code that does what I mentioned. Actually it works. However, what is strange is that it works everytime but the first! When I push the button to launch the Async process for the first time, the progressDialog is not shown, eventhough "onPreExecute()" is called and the line "progressDialog.show()" executed. If I rotate the screen after I push the button the progressDialog shows and when the process ends, If I push the button again then it works just fine. As I said, it is working all the time except the first one. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Activity

```
 public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityTaskFragment.TaskCallbacks{

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";
private ActivityTaskFragment activityTaskFragment;

//Some additional code here 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crear_turno);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //------------------------------------------------------

    setListeners();
    setFragment();
    createProgressDialog();
    showProgressDialog();
}

private void showProgressDialog()
{
    if(activityTaskFragment!=null)
    {
        if(activityTaskFragment.isRunning())
        {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
}

private void setFragment()
{
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    activityTaskFragment = (ActivityTaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

    // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
    // retained across a configuration change.
    if (activityTaskFragment == null) {
        activityTaskFragment = new ActivityTaskFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(activityTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
}


private void setListeners() {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activityTaskFragment.execute();
        }
    });


}

//fragment interface implementation

@Override
public void onPreExecute()
{
    if(progressDialog!=null)
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onCancelled() {
    if(progressDialog!=null)
    {
        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute()
{
    if(progressDialog!=null)
    {
        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();        
        }
    }


}

private void createProgressDialog()

{
    if(progressDialog == null)
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Executing job");
        progressDialog.setMessage("please wait...");

    }

}
```

}

TaskFragment

```
/**
* This Fragment manages a single background task and retains
* itself across configuration changes.
*/
public class ActivityTaskFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Callback interface through which the fragment will report the
 * task's progress and results back to the Activity.
 */
interface TaskCallbacks {
    void onPreExecute();
    void onCancelled();
    void onPostExecute();
}

private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
private CheckTask mTask;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
}

/**
 * Hold a reference to the parent Activity so we can report the
 * task's current progress and results. The Android framework
 * will pass us a reference to the newly created Activity after
 * each configuration change.
 */

public void execute()
{
    mTask.cancel(true);
    mTask = new CheckTask();
    mTask.execute();
}

public void cancel()
{
    if(mTask != null)
    {
        mTask.cancel(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof Activity) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
    }
}

/**
 * This method will only be called once when the retained
 * Fragment is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);
    mTask = new CheckTask();

}

/**
 * Set the callback to null so we don't accidentally leak the
 * Activity instance.
 */
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

/**
 * A dummy task that performs some (dumb) background work and
 * proxies progress updates and results back to the Activity.
 *
 * Note that we need to check if the callbacks are null in each
 * method in case they are invoked after the Activity's and
 * Fragment's onDestroy() method have been called.
 */
private class CheckTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Note that we do NOT call the callback object's methods
     * directly from the background thread, as this could result
     * in a race condition.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {

        /*
            LONG TIME CONSUMING TASK
        */

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        running = false;
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onCancelled();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore)
    {
        running = false;
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onPostExecute();
        }
    }
}

public boolean isRunning()
{
    if(mTask!=null)
    {
        if(mTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: when you say it does not show are you talking about the onCreate call

Comment: nope, I am talking about the progressDialog. Lets say, I push the button and it is supposed to appear a progressDialog showing some tasks are performed on the background. But no, nothing appears. However, if I rotate the screen or next time I push the button, it works as expected, this is, showin the progressDialog just after I push the button.

Comment: Why is onAttach(...) implemented twice in ActivityTaskFragment?

Comment: This is to support the deprecated method ( I am using sdk 21 ) so it is calling the deprecated method not the new one